# Nested indirect lookup in excel

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel table - see attached screenshot.

need enter an formula into column `J` for getting a value from a region `C2:E10`, based on the values from the columns `G,H,I`.

So, what formula shold enter into cell `J2` for get the value from the cell `E3`. (indexes are in g,h,i columns),

This mean some nested indirect lookup - and haven't idea how to do it.

[image]

Comment: If you create a helper column which concatenates A and B then you can use vlookup on that column to get the row, and MATCH() on C1:E1 to get the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula in J2 copied down

`=INDEX(C$2:E$10,MATCH(1,INDEX((A$2:A$10=G2)*(B$2:B$10=H2),0),0),MATCH(I2,C$1:E$1,0))`

Answer (score 1):

I need 3 cells - seems excel doesn't do nested array formulas (or I can't get them to work)

J2 `=MATCH(G2&H2,A2:A10&B2:B10,0)`  {Enter as an *array* formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)
K2 `=MATCH(I2,C2:E2)`
L2 `=INDEX(C2:E10,J2,K2)`

Comment: You should be able to make that into one array formula, Sean - it's effectively the same as mine but the second INDEX function in my suggestion allows you to enter without "CSE"

Comment: Works too, accepted the "one-cell" solution from @barry. Thanx anyway. +1